# How to update record in OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload.preCombine

Tags: apache-flink, apache-hudi

1. I have a requirement where I need to combine fields from old and new records in OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload.preCombine
2. The default behaviour either selects old-record or `this` based on ordering Value.
3. But in my case I need to combine fields from both old and new in same record before returning value.
4. To be able to do this, I am trying to first convert `OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload` to GenericRecord so that I can modify field values.
5. In below code, if I return `newRec` as it is, it works as expected i.e. first  `preCombine` is called and then `combineAndGetUpdateValue` is called.
6. But if I return newRec1 i.e. when I convert `GenericRecord` back to `OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload` it doesn't work. I.e. `preCombine` is called but `combineAndGetUpdateValue` is not called.
7. So the question is, how can I modify the record in preCombine before returning.

```java
    public OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload preCombine(OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload oldValue) {
        OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload newRec = super.preCombine(oldValue);

        try {
            OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload newRec1 = new OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload(HoodieAvroUtils.bytesToAvro(newRec.recordBytes,defaultSchema), newRec.orderingVal);
            System.out.println(HoodieAvroUtils.avroToJson(HoodieAvroUtils.bytesToAvro(newRec.recordBytes,defaultSchema),true));
            return newRec1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return newRec;
        }
    }
```

See above. tried with both

```java
OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload newRec1 = new OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload(HoodieAvroUtils.bytesToAvro(newRec.recordBytes,defaultSchema), newRec.orderingVal);
```

and

```java
OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload(HoodieAvroUtils.bytesToAvro(HoodieAvroUtils.indexedRecordToBytes(newValue), defaultSchema), oldValue.orderingVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing to following line, it worked. Bottomline is make sure the object instance that you are creating is an instance of your payload class and not the generic OverwriteWithLatestAvroPayload.

```java
MsgDetailPayload newRec1 = new MsgDetailPayload(HoodieAvroUtils.bytesToAvro(newRec.recordBytes,defaultSchema), newRec.orderingVal);
```